# Actian/Pervasive SQL and Date Variables

Tags: date, odbc, pervasive, actian

How are date variables declared and used in Actian Zen/Pervasive ?

How do i fix this

```
    CREATE proc test1 ()
returns(TranDate integer, GLAcntNumber integer , Net decimal(39,19))
as BEGIN 
    
DECLARE :StartDate DATE ;
SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) INTO :StartDate ;
SELECT :StartDate , GLAcntNumber, SUM(Net) AS Amt 
FROM vGLBalances 
WHERE period < 1
GROUP BY :StartDate, GLAcntNumber;

END
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, What error are you getting?  What version of Actian/Pervasive are you using?

Comment: Zen Install Version 14.20.012

Answer (score 0):

I take that back.  I do see something in your query.  You are creating a DATE but are trying to pass it back as an INTEGER.  Change your query to:

```
CREATE procedure test1 ()
returns(TranDate date, GLAcntNumber integer , Net decimal(39,19))
as BEGIN 
    
DECLARE :StartDate DATE ;
SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) INTO :StartDate ;
SELECT :StartDate, GLAcntNumber, SUM(Net) AS Amt 
FROM vGLBalances 
WHERE period < 1
GROUP BY :StartDate, GLAcntNumber;

END
```

It should work.  If you really want an Integer instead of a date, you'll need to change the query from using a date.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake - i did have it as date and  i tried the integer then changed it back (incompletely)

It returns an error every time

Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [37000]: [LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: CREATE proc<< ??? >> test1 ()

Comment: I figured it out.  use CREATE PROCEDURE  (no shortcuts)